# Postgresql array sum

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Given an array column in a table of a PostgreSQL database containing the following:

```
{{765,4},{767,3},{569,5},{567,3},{725,5}}
```

How could I calculate the sum of all second elements of each subarray,
i.e. 4+3+5+3+5

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `UNNEST` which expands an array to a set of rows, and filtering by the row number:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT SUM(v) 
    FROM UNNEST(array_column) WITH ORDINALITY a(v, n) 
    WHERE n % 2 = 0
) FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thank you clemens. However, when you UNNEST the array_column, you get a column of integers, not an array, so it cannot be subscripted: The result of the UNNEST is:
765
4
767
3
569
5
567
3
725
5

Comment: Ok, this is a little bit more (dirty) tricky. I adapted my query, and added the row number to identify the even rows from unnest.

Comment: Thanks, Was not aware of ORDINALITY, but it doesn't resolve my real issue  The array contains pairs of questionid and user_response, i.e. {765,4} questionid=765/response=4. I didn't provide enough info. I was avoiding using a user_respones table (userid, questionid, response) by putting an array or json in a field in the user table. I need to query for the sum of various responses by groups of questionid's. Easy with a user_response table, but was trying to take advantage of Postgresql's array or json data types. I probably should just use the user_respones table approach and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my objective presented here by using jsonb array.
The jsonbArray  
`[{"an": 4, "qid": 765}, {"an": 3, "qid": 767}, {"an": 5, "qid": 569}, {"an": 3, "qid": 567}, {"an": 5, "qid": 725}]`
The query that accomplishes the objective:

```
WITH answers as (
    SELECT
        (jsonbArray -> 'an')::int as an,
        (jsonbArray -> 'qid')::int as qid
    FROM (
        SELECT jsonb_array_elements(jsonbArray) AS jsonbArray
        FROM user where id = 1
        ) AS s
    group by qid, an
    )
select sum(an) as score from answers where qid in (765,725)

Result: 
score
9
```